# SSRS Report. Passing multiple values to a single parameter in a new report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a two charts in a SSRS report that jump to the same report.  I would like to pass values to the new report that are different for each chart.  I would like to define those values myself and pass them through a parameter to the dataset of the jump report.  How can I do this?  The datatype for Division is INT and I'm getting a conversion to ncharvalue error.

Example:

Chart1 - Parameter @Division - Values - 1000,2000,3000,3500,5000,8000

Chart2 - Parameter @Division - Values - 6000,7000

ds_JumpToReport

SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Division IN (@Division)

I have tried using the following as a value for the parameter in the dataset:

=JOIN(Parameters!Division.Value,",")

However, I get an error with that too.  "The value provided for the report parameter 'Division' is not valid for its type."

If I DECLARE @Division nvarchar(max); in the query, I get no results back on the report.

Comment: You are comparing an int to nvarchar when you use the join which creates a comma-separated string.

Comment: So, how do I resolve that?

Comment: That's why I left a comment not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the many forms of the Split function (google "tsql split function" for some examples) to turn your comma-delimited string into a table.  Then just change your ds_JumpToReport to:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table 
WHERE Division IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.Split(@Division))
```